# Is there anyway to disable quantity edit in magento?

Tags: magento

As my title says, Is there anyway to disable the quantity edit in magento shopping cart? Currently, I can see the textbox there in the magento. I want to see the quantity in plain text or the textbox disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `.phtml` file for this is in `app/design/frontend/base/default/checkout` so if it is, you can copy the file and paste it into your own custom theme (`app/design/frontend/[custom_package]/[custom_theme]/template/checkout/...`).

Modify the textbox to be readonly, or however you'd like, in that `.phtml` template file.

Note, it is *not* good practice to modify core files. For `app/design/` code, it's better to make your own package/theme and copy/paste the default content over and modify it there (be sure your package/theme is set in the admin panel).

**ORGINAL FILE LOCATION**: `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item`

Comment: there's no any checkout folder

Comment: Sure there is `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout`. If it's not /base/default/, then check /default/default/ or whatever other package/theme you have

Comment: it was here `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart/item`, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, go to following path app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml.

```
  <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
        <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Edit the Input Tag to text or comment it out as your wish

Comment: How to edit the same thing in the cart?? Its about the product page (Add to Cart).

Comment: if its cart page then follow @Shredder suggestion.